# Постепенно закрасить все координаты плоскости с интервалом в 1 секунду

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация, canvas

Необходимо закрасить все поле вот таким вот образом, как на изображении (квадрат должен увеличиваться на 3 клетки во все стороны каждую секунду). Проблема в том, что на середине программа начинает тормозить и с каждым новым вызовом функции все медленнее и медленнее работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать программу, чтобы поле заполнялось корректно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  let field = document.getElementById('field')
function addCell(field) {
    let coordinates = [], i, j;
    for(i = 0; i<50; i++) {
        coordinates[i] = new Array()
        for (j = 0; j<50; j++){
            let cell = document.createElement('div')
            cell.setAttribute('class','cell')
            cell.setAttribute('x',(i+1).toString())
            cell.setAttribute('y',(j+1).toString())
            coordinates[i][j] = cell
            field.appendChild(cell)
        }
    } return coordinates
}

let coordinates = addCell(field)

function setBomb(coordinates) {
    function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    }

    let x = getRandomInt(coordinates.length)
    let y = getRandomInt(coordinates.length)

    function setAffected(coordinates, x, y) {
        if(coordinates[x][y].getAttribute('class') === 'cell') {
            if ((x >= 0) && (x < coordinates.length) && (y >= 0) && (y < coordinates.length)) {
                coordinates[x][y].setAttribute('class', 'affected')
            }
        }else return
    }
    setAffected(coordinates,x,y)
    getCoords(coordinates,x,y)
    function getCoords(coordinates,x,y) {
        let yright1 = y + 1
        let yright2 = y + 2
        let yleft1 = y - 1
        let yleft2 = y - 2
        let xtop1 = x + 1
        let xtop2 = x + 2
        let xbot1 = x - 1
        let xbot2 = x - 2
        setAffected(coordinates, x, yright1)
        setAffected(coordinates, x, yright2)
        setAffected(coordinates, x, yleft1)
        setAffected(coordinates, x, yleft2)
        setAffected(coordinates, xtop1, y)
        setAffected(coordinates, xtop2, y)
        setAffected(coordinates, xbot1, y)
        setAffected(coordinates, xbot2, y)
        setAffected(coordinates, xtop1, yright1)
        setAffected(coordinates, xtop1, yright2)
        setAffected(coordinates, xtop2, yright1)
        setAffected(coordinates, xtop2, yright2)
        setAffected(coordinates, xtop1, yleft1)
        setAffected(coordinates, xtop1, yleft2)
        setAffected(coordinates, xtop2, yleft1)
        setAffected(coordinates, xtop2, yleft2)
        setAffected(coordinates, xtop1, yright2)
        setAffected(coordinates, xbot1, yleft1)
        setAffected(coordinates, xbot1, yleft2)
        setAffected(coordinates, xbot2, yleft1)
        setAffected(coordinates, xbot2, yleft2)
        setAffected(coordinates, xbot1, yright1)
        setAffected(coordinates, xbot1, yright2)
        setAffected(coordinates, xbot2, yright1)
        setAffected(coordinates, xbot2, yright2)
        function explode(coordinates,xtop1,xtop2,yright2,yleft2){
            getCoords(coordinates, xtop2, yright2)
            getCoords(coordinates, xtop2, yleft2)
            getCoords(coordinates, xbot2, yleft2)
            getCoords(coordinates, xbot2, yright2)
        }
        return setTimeout(explode,1000,coordinates,xtop1,xtop2,yright2,yleft2)

    }

}

setBomb(coordinates)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу только предложить свое решение на canvas. Тут вообще нечему тормозить. Можно решетку перенести на другой слой и тогда рисовать квадраты раз в секунду будет еще менее затратней)))

Пока идет взрыв, закладывать нельзя. Можно это убрать.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const w = canvas.width = 400;
const h = canvas.height = 400;
const col_num = 50;
const row_num = 50;

const cell_w = w / col_num;
const cell_h = h / row_num;

is_exploding = false;

drawNet();
canvas.addEventListener('click', setBomb);

function drawNet() {
  let net_path = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < col_num + 1; i++) {
    net_path += `M ${i*cell_w} 0 V ${h} `;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < row_num + 1; i++) {
    net_path += `M 0 ${i*cell_h} H ${w} `;
  }
  ctx.stroke(new Path2D(net_path));
}

function explode(c_x, c_y, blow_radius) {
  is_exploding = true;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  const x = (c_x - blow_radius) * cell_w;
  const y = (c_y - blow_radius) * cell_h;
  const blow_w = (blow_radius * 2 + 1) * cell_w;
  const blow_h = (blow_radius * 2 + 1) * cell_h;

  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, blow_w, blow_h);
  ctx.restore();

  drawNet();

  const max_dist_to_edge = Math.max((c_x - blow_radius),
    (col_num - c_x - blow_radius - 1),
    (c_y - blow_radius),
    (row_num - c_y - blow_radius - 1));

  if (max_dist_to_edge > 0) {
    blow_radius += 3;
    setTimeout(() => explode(c_x, c_y, blow_radius), 1000);
  } else {
    is_exploding = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
      drawNet();
    }, 2000);
  }
}

function setBomb(e) {
  if (!is_exploding) {
    const x = e.offsetX;
    const y = e.offsetY;
    const c_x = Math.floor(x / cell_w);
    const c_y = Math.floor(y / cell_h);
    explode(c_x, c_y, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<p style="position:fixed; right:20px; top:20px">Кликните на клетку<br> для запуска устройства</p>
```

Увеличил поле и теперь можно взрывать одновременно в нескольких точках, сетку перенес на другой холст. Можете попробовать "загрузить" анимацию, одновременно натыкав десятки взрывов.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const w = canvas.width = net.width = 2000;
const h = canvas.height = net.height = 1200;
const col_num = 400;
const row_num = 240;

const cell_w = w / col_num;
const cell_h = h / row_num;

drawNet();
canvas.addEventListener('click', setBomb);

function drawNet() {
  let net_path = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < col_num + 1; i++) {
    net_path += `M ${i*cell_w} 0 V ${h} `;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < row_num + 1; i++) {
    net_path += `M 0 ${i*cell_h} H ${w} `;
  }
  net.getContext('2d').stroke(new Path2D(net_path));
}

function explode(c_x, c_y, blow_radius) {

  const x = (c_x - blow_radius) * cell_w;
  const y = (c_y - blow_radius) * cell_h;
  const blow_w = (blow_radius * 2 + 1) * cell_w;
  const blow_h = (blow_radius * 2 + 1) * cell_h;

  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, blow_w, blow_h);
  ctx.restore();

  const max_dist_to_edge = Math.max((c_x - blow_radius),
    (col_num - c_x - blow_radius - 1),
    (c_y - blow_radius),
    (row_num - c_y - blow_radius - 1));

  if (max_dist_to_edge > 0) {
    blow_radius += 3;
    setTimeout(() => explode(c_x, c_y, blow_radius), 1000);
  }
}

function setBomb(e) {
  const x = e.offsetX;
  const y = e.offsetY;
  const c_x = Math.floor(x / cell_w);
  const c_y = Math.floor(y / cell_h);
  explode(c_x, c_y, 1);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#net {
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas id="net"></canvas>
```

**Или можно добавить еще цвета))**

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const w = canvas.width = net.width = 2000;
const h = canvas.height = net.height = 1200;
const col_num = 400;
const row_num = 240;

const cell_w = w / col_num;
const cell_h = h / row_num;

drawNet();
canvas.addEventListener('click', setBomb);

function drawNet() {
  let net_path = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < col_num + 1; i++) {
    net_path += `M ${i*cell_w} 0 V ${h} `;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < row_num + 1; i++) {
    net_path += `M 0 ${i*cell_h} H ${w} `;
  }
  net.getContext('2d').stroke(new Path2D(net_path));
}

function explode(c_x, c_y, blow_radius, color){
    
    const x = (c_x - blow_radius)*cell_w;
    const y = (c_y - blow_radius)*cell_h;
    const blow_w = (blow_radius*2 + 1)*cell_w;
    const blow_h = (blow_radius*2 + 1)*cell_h;
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,blow_w,blow_h);
    ctx.restore();
    
    const max_dist_to_edge = Math.max((c_x - blow_radius),
                                   (col_num - c_x - blow_radius - 1),
                                   (c_y - blow_radius),
                                   (row_num - c_y - blow_radius - 1));
    
    if(max_dist_to_edge > 0){
        blow_radius += 10;
        setTimeout(() => explode(c_x, c_y, blow_radius, color), 100);
    }
}

function setBomb(e){
        const x = e.offsetX;
        const y = e.offsetY;
        const c_x = Math.floor(x/cell_w);
        const c_y = Math.floor(y/cell_h);
        
        const random_color = `rgb(${random255()},${random255()},${random255()})`;
        explode(c_x,c_y,1,random_color);
}

function random255(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#net {
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas id="net"></canvas>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Очень сильно выручили.

Comment: Не знаю, что вам здесь подойдет, но спасибо за развлечение))

Comment: @Leonid Ну вот, пошёл  в движение понемногу раздел Canvas/  Замечательный ответ Леонид!  В конце надо бы, как-то останавливать анимацию после заполнения всего свободного пространства. А то как то всё беспорядочно начинает моргать

Comment: Там и тормозится, только когда каждый из цветов заполнит полностью все поле, а двигается медленно, по 3 клетки, вот и ждать долго. В конце поле будет закрашено в цвет последней "бомбы". Сейчас ускорю немного)) Ускорил! Поправочка: останется цвет той бомбы, которая займет все поле последней.

Comment: Вообще да, надо помещать каждую бомбу в массив-очередь, и отрисовывать с определенной частотой каждую бомбу с новым радиусом и в определенном порядке все вместе, тогда не будет мигать. Но это же просто для демонстрации отсутствия задержек, загрузок и так далее.

Comment: @Leonid Протестировал оба варианта. Особенно понравился крайний вариант. Очень динамично, зрелищно, впечатляют эти эффекты, тем более они реализованы со сравнительно малым количеством кода. Мощно, зачёт!